# Complexifications of degree 3 subschemes in $\mathbb A^2_{\mathbb R}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, schemes, affine-schemes

I am trying unsuccessfully to solve exercise II-20 (page 65) from the book "The geometry of schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris. In this exercise it is stated that there are two non-isomorphic subschemes of degree three in $A^2_{\mathbb R}$ supported at $(0,0)$ that become isomorhic to $Spec\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ after complexification.

Could you give me a hint on what is the solution?

Comment: What does length mean?

Comment: I was made a mistake! (sorry for that) I was supposes to say "degree", and not "length" ... In this context the scheme is given by an ideal $I\subset \mathbb R[x,y]$, and its degree is the dimension of $\mathbb R[x,y]/I$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$ (as far as I understand). Moreover $I$ should belong to some power of the ideal $(x,y)$ - this means that the corresponding scheme is supported at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the ring.   Its residue field $k$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
But then  $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} A$ admits a surjection onto $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} k.$
Since this base-change is local by assumption, with residue field $\mathbb C$, we see
that necessarily $k = \mathbb R$.

Since the maximal ideal of $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} A$ has square zero,
the maximal ideal of $A$ must also have square zero.

So we can write $A = \mathbb R \oplus \mathfrak m,$
where $\mathfrak m^2 = 0$.

---

This answer seems to contradict the claim in Eisenbud and Harris --- namely
it suggests that $A$ is uniquely determined up to isomorphism as the direct sum
$\mathbb R \oplus \mathfrak m$, where $\mathfrak m$ is a two-dimensional $\mathbb R$-v.s. which is declared to be of square zero.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I guess this means indeed that there is a mistake in this exercise. Maybe it is worth to write to the authors of this book...